# custom field not saved

Tags: custom-field, metabox

help me please:

my custom metabox not save !!

```
#add a metabox
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'adding_meta_box' );
function adding_meta_box()
{
add_meta_box( 'meta_box_id', 'اطلاعات پست', 'frst_meta_box', 'page_news_letter', 'normal', 'high' );
}
function frst_meta_box( $post )
{
$value = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
$text_field_one = isset( $value['news_one'] ) ? esc_attr(     $value['news_one'][0] ) : '';
wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>
<?php 
$my_custom_query= new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'cat'   =>  '1',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'ID',
'posts_per_page' =>'10',
'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 
)); ?> 
<?php 
if($my_custom_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<select name="news_one" id="news_one">
<?php while($my_custom_query->have_posts()) : $my_custom_query->the_post();?>
<option value="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</select>

#saving metabox
add_action( 'save_post', 'saving_meta_box' );
function saving_meta_box( $post_id )
{
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce(     $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;
$accepted_field = array(
  'a' => array('href' => array() )
);
if( isset( $_POST['news_one'] ) )
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'news_one', wp_kses( $_POST['news_one'],     $accepted_field ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong, your custom field is saved but you won't see the value pre-selected in the select box. To see it you have to set the `selected` attribute of the `select` element. You can do it easily with [`selected()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected). You should also escape the attribute values and, in your case, use `wp_reset_postdata` instead of `wp_reset_query`:

```
if($my_custom_query->have_posts()) : ?>

    <select name="news_one" id="news_one">

        <?php while($my_custom_query->have_posts()) :

             $my_custom_query->the_post();

             $title = get_the_title();

             ?>

            <option value="<?php esc_attr_e($title); ?>" <?php selected(  $text_field_one, $title ); ?>><?php echo $title; ?></option>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: tanx my freind :)

Comment: how i do it????

Comment: Bellow the up/dow voting buttons, at the top-left of the answer, there is a check mark.